# Inhering colours from div to anther in CSS only

Tags: javascript, css

Lets say I have 3 Div's, one called A and the others are B and C, in the CSS, Div A, B and C will always have the same background-color as it is shown in the CSS example below...

```
div .A {
   background-color: black;
}

div .B {
   background-color: black;
}

div .C {
   background-color: black;
}
```

My question: Is there anyway I can change the background colour on div A, and then the other divs B and C will actually pull whatever colour applied to A and inherit it? Can I do that using CSS only?

Comment: That would depend on the structure of your HTML. In some cases it would be possible, in other cases, no.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? thank you.

Comment: You may want to look into using a CSS compiler like LESS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to make `div .A` a parent of `div .B` and `div .C` then set the `background` property on B and C to `inherit`. This way, B and C (children of A) literally inherit from their parent.

Or, you can make a different class (say "parent") and have `div .B`, `div .C` *and* `div .A` inherit from `div .parent`.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="A"></div>
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
</div>

.parent {
    background: red;
}

.A {
    background: black; /* let's change this for the sake of being rogue */
}

.B, .C {
    background: inherit; /* will inherit "red" from .parent */
}
```

Comment: I believe that will work, as the Div A is in my case (the body) and Div B is (the footer). and the footer is inside the body...

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, no.

There's nothing like class-level inheritance on CSS classes.  Properties can propagate through the DOM hierarchy, but there's no straightforward way to make class B and C inherit the background-color from the definition of A.  For properties that you want to share in common, you'd typically just apply a common class to those DOM elements.

To put it another way, you can't construct the desired relationship between A, B and C solely in the CSS.  With the right DOM, you could do it.  But if you don't want B and C to be a child of A in the DOM, then you're out of luck.